# GitHub Action: Pass Environment Variable to into Action using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, github-actions

I am using trying to build a workflow that will run in PowerShell.  I am setting an environment for my branch name to use in a step for checkout of a different repository.

```
run: |
  $branchName = $Env:GITHUB_REF -replace "refs/heads/", ""
  echo "CURRENT_BRANCH=${branchName}" | Out-File -FilePath $Env:GITHUB_ENV -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

In a later step, I'm trying to pass in the variable:

```
- name: Checkout repo  
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: 'MyOrg/MyRepo'
    ref: ${env:CURRENT_BRANCH}
```

I've tried different formats involving curly brackets, but I keep getting output from the build that shows that exact text as the path.  I'm not sure sure how to get it to evaluate.
When I do  `${{ env:CURRENT_BRANCH }}` I received the following error:

> The workflow is not valid.
> .github/workflows/publish.yml (Line: 54, Col: 14):
> Unexpected symbol: 'env:CURRENT_BRANCH'. Located at position 1
> within expression: env:CURRENT_BRANCH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reference a variable from the given context (`env` in this case) in the GitHub Actions workflow we have to use a dot (`.`) character, but you used a colon (`:`). To fix the error above the workflow should be adjusted:

```
- name: Checkout repo  
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: 'MyOrg/MyRepo'
    ref: ${{env.CURRENT_BRANCH}}
```

Additionally, you don't have to detect the current branch on and pass it to the checkout action. [`actions/checkout@v2`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) will use the current branch by default. So you only have to have:

```
- name: Checkout repo  
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Next Step
[...]
```

Comment: To your second point: I am checking out two repositories.  The first, which is where the action is executing from, will choose the right branch.  However, the second repository is using `Master`.  Is that what you would expect?

Comment: I know that I had tried that before, but maybe I had something else screwed up.  That worked this time!  Actions are exhausting.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'` Although, I'm trying to call it from a Job calling a reusable workflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working method now, [more info here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/):

`echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

The one below no longer works for me. A bit of research showed it is due to a [security issue](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files).

`echo "::set-output name=action_state::yellow"`

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found elsewhere and will post it here as an option, although I would like to know if using Environment Variables is possibly in my scenario.
The solution is to use [Outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) from a Step

```
- name: Output Variables
  id: SetVariables
  run: |
    $branchName = $Env:GITHUB_REF -replace "refs/heads/", ""
    echo "Branch: ${branchName}"
    echo "::set-output name=branch::${branchName}"

- name: Checkout Repo 2
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: 'MyOrg/MyRepo'
    ref: ${{ steps.SetVariables.outputs.branch }}
```